# How to increase expiry of google oauth token in .net core

Tags: c#, google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using .net core web api & google oauth token. it's existing expiry time is 1 hour. how to increase it's expiry time to 5 hour.

Comment: Why? Just refresh it when it expires...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: You can not increase the expire time of a token.

The authorization token you are seeing is called an access token, this grants you access to a users data for one hour.  It can not be extended.

When requesting authorization of the user you should include offline access scope then you will get a refresh token back.  A refresh token for the most part does not expire.  You can use the refresh token to request a new access token when ever you need one.